# calling onclick methods from other methods

Tags: jquery, function

Is it possible to have two Jquery functions like follows

```
$('#id1').on('click', function(){
    //body
}


$('#id2').on('click', function(){
    //body
}
```

but to be able to call the body of

```
$('#id2').on('click', function(){} );
```

in

```
$('#id1').on('click', function(){} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you could either:

1. [Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click) and call the function that way:

   ```
   $('#id2').click();
   ```
2. Name the function and call it directly:

   ```
   function myClickFn() {
       // ..
   }

   $('#id2').on('click', myClickFn);
   $('#id1').on('click', function () {
       myClickFn();
   });
   ```

I would strongly recommend option #2.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$("#id2").on('click', function() {
    $("#id1").trigger("click");
});
```

This will actually trigger the click event on that id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have each function call a third, common, function:

```
$('#id1').on('click', function(){
    doCommon()
}


$('#id2').on('click', function(){
    doCommon()
}

function doCommon(){
    alert('here i am');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#id1').on('click', function(){
    //body
    $('#id2').trigger('click');
}


$('#id2').on('click', function(){
    //body
}
```